# What is the meaning of Brown-Bagged it?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Some unknown guy punched Brendan. Brendan appeared before V.P Trueman.

> V.P Trueman: So you didn't know this boy?
>
> Brendan: No sir, never seen him.
>
> V.P Trueman: And he just hit you?
>
> Brendan:Like I said, he asked for my lunch money first. Good thing I
>   **brown-bagged it**.

In google, Brown-Bagged is related to sex, but here context is so different.

Comment: What is V.P.? Vice president of the USA?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As an international student in the U.S., I was puzzled first time I received an invitation to a "brown bag lunch seminar" in our department. Turned out, it means that lunch isn't served, but everybody was expected to bring their own lunch. And it would often be packed in a brown paper bag (they sell them in stores), hence the name.

So in this context "I brown-bagged it" means that Brendan didn't have any lunch money, but brought his own lunch with him (which may or may not have been in an actual brown bag).

Comment: You seem to be missing a reference.  Try this: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/brown-bag+lunch

Comment: @Flater Hiding alcohol isn't a requirement - it's simply illegal to drink alcohol in public in many places in the US.  The brown bag, in that case, is usually a weak attempt to disguise the illegal activity.  In any case, that isn't the meaning in OP's quote.  The implied meaning is clear - that Brendan didn't *have* any lunch money because he instead brought a lunch with him.

Comment: +1 You have the correct interpretation. The bully asked for Brendan's lunch money, but Brendan didn't have any because he had brought his lunch from home. It is unlikely in the extreme that a school kid would tell the vice principal (school official, often in charge of discipline) that he had been carrying a container of liquor.

Comment: @Flater You're trying to apply grammar rules too strictly here.  The phrasing `I brown bagged it` is sort of a colloquial or idiomatic expression.  You might use it like `Joe : Hey want to go out for lunch Jim?`, `Jim : Nah, I brown-bagged it today`.  Here, "it" refers to the lunch.

Comment: @Flater To ["brown bag **it**" is a common idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/brown-bag+it), meaning to bring one's own lunch.

Comment: Just to add the image, since it's a reference to the [ubiquitous Brown Bags](http://s.eatthis-cdn.com/media/images/ext/885344926/brown-bag-lunch-blunders-packing-on-pounds.jpg) found in most American school cafeterias.

Comment: In 4 years of employment I've never bothered to learn what a brown bag meeting was, I thought Brown Bag were a client of ours or something. Today I learned.

Comment: If he'd used a lunch-box instead, he would have had a handy weapon.

Comment: @zipirovich, you'd hate our office. We host brown bag meetings where no one brings lunch and due to global dial ins they are often not even at lunchtime. For us it's come to mean an informal meeting where information conveyed is not directly related to work function. For instance,  "We're going to tell them about the new campus plans through a series of brown bags".